# does change in preferences commit then and there or need to call activity again?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this code:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean hasLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

    if (!((LoginButton.email).equals(""))) {

        //settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        // Set "hasLoggedIn" to true
        editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
        Log.d("hasLoggedIn in email check = ", hasLoggedIn + "");
    }
}
```

even after entering the if, the last Log gives me hadLoggedIn as false.

Somewhere in the same activity i got the same code of editing which works fine, but the only difference is i never used it as soon as it got edited, i used it when the activity is called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will again have to open sharedpreference for reading.

**your hasLoggedIn still contains old value.**

I have updated your code as below.

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean hasLoggedIn = settings.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);

    if (!((LoginButton.email).equals(""))) {

        //settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        // Set "hasLoggedIn" to true
        editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();

        //You forgot write following line.
        hasLoggedIn = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false); 
        Log.d("hasLoggedIn in email check = ", hasLoggedIn + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean i should uncomment settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); ??